# Minha conta do meta tem 10 pontos a menos

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, reputação, meta

Acredito que a pontuação do meta na verdade deveria ser a mesma da comunidade principal, já que os ponto no meta não são contabilizados (ou não são considerados diretamente).

[image: erro na pontuação]

Realmente não sei quando o problema começou (se é que realmente isto seja uma falha).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é normal, a conta do meta leva um tempo para sincronizar a pontuação.

Comment: Faz 2 dias e quando eu ganho alguma pontuação e aqui fica -10. Outra coisa, sempre que ganho pontos na comunidade principal aqui altera na mesma hora, acabei de ganhar +10 (no SOpt estava 1917 e meta 1907). Para ter certeza vou esperar ao longo do dia :)

Comment: A reputação aqui é lida de um cache, que acredito ser atualizado algumas vezes por dia.

Comment: Aconteceu de novo hoje, mas em poucos minutos voltou ao normal. Penso eu que foi algum conflito, mas uma nova "verificação" do cache corrigiu.